# XCMS Package - Retention time

Tags: r, bioconductor

Is there a simple way to get the list/array of retention times from a `xcmsRaw` object?

Example Code:

```
xraw <- xcmsRaw(cdfFile)
```

So for example getting information from it :

```
xraw@env$intensity
```

or

```
xraw@env$mz
```

Comment: I don't know anything about that package, but the documentation suggests that this may be what you're after `xraw@msnRt` ?

Comment: Ok i tried your solution but for a real data it does not return anything. But you're right there it should be ....

Comment: Possibly because there is no retention time information in the object you are using, but that's where the information is expected to be. From `class@xcmsRaw`: `msnRt: Retention time of the scan`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see what slots are available in your `xcmsRaw` instance with

```
> slotNames(xraw)
 [1] "env"                   "tic"                   "scantime"             
 [4] "scanindex"             "polarity"              "acquisitionNum"       
 [7] "profmethod"            "profparam"             "mzrange"              
[10] "gradient"              "msnScanindex"          "msnAcquisitionNum"    
[13] "msnPrecursorScan"      "msnLevel"              "msnRt"                
[16] "msnPrecursorMz"        "msnPrecursorIntensity" "msnPrecursorCharge"   
[19] "msnCollisionEnergy"    "filepath"
```

What you want is `xraw@msnRt` - it is a `vector` of `numeric`.

The `env` slot is a environment that stores 3 variables:

```
> ls(xraw@env)
[1] "intensity" "mz"        "profile"
```

More details on the class itself at `class?xcmsRaw`.

**EDIT:** The `msnRt` slot is populated only if you specify `includeMSn = TRUE` and your input file must be in `mzXML` or `mzML`, not in `cdf`; if you use the `faahKO` example from `?xcmasRaw`, you will see that

```
xr <- xcmsRaw(cdffiles[1], includeMSn = TRUE)
Warning message:
In xcmsRaw(cdffiles[1], includeMSn = TRUE) :
  Reading of MSn spectra for NetCDF not supported
```

Also, `xr@msnRt` will only store the retention times for MSn scans, with `n > 1`. See the `xset@rt` where `xset` is an `xcmsSet` instance for the raw/corrected MS1 retention times as provided by `xcms`.

**EDIT2:** Alternatively, have a go with the [`mzR`](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/mzR.html) package

```
> library(mzR)
> cdffiles[1]
[2] "/home/lgatto/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/2.16/faahKO/cdf/KO/ko15.CDF"
> xx <- openMSfile(cdffiles[1])
> xx
Mass Spectrometry file handle.
Filename:  /home/lgatto/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/2.16/faahKO/cdf/KO/ko15.CDF 
Number of scans:  1278 
> hd <- header(xx)
> names(hd)
 [1] "seqNum"                   "acquisitionNum"          
 [3] "msLevel"                  "peaksCount"              
 [5] "totIonCurrent"            "retentionTime"           
 [7] "basePeakMZ"               "basePeakIntensity"       
 [9] "collisionEnergy"          "ionisationEnergy"        
[11] "highMZ"                   "precursorScanNum"        
[13] "precursorMZ"              "precursorCharge"         
[15] "precursorIntensity"       "mergedScan"              
[17] "mergedResultScanNum"      "mergedResultStartScanNum"
[19] "mergedResultEndScanNum"  
> class(hd)
[1] "data.frame"
> dim(hd)
[1] 1278   19
```

but you will be outside of the default `xcms` pipeline if you take this route (although Steffen Neumann, from `xcms`, does know `mzR` very well, oubviously).

Finally, you are better of to use the Bioconductor [mailing list](http://bioconductor.org/help/mailing-list/) of the [`xcms` online forum](http://www.metabolomics-forum.com/viewforum.php?f=10) if you want to maximise your chances to get feedback from the `xcms` developers.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I consider it a good unswer but I've done a post about what I actually wanted to do!!!

Answer (score 0):

Good answer but i was looking for this :

```
xraw <- xcmsRaw(cdfFile)
dp_index <- which(duplicated(rawMat(xraw)[,1]))
xraw_rt_dp <- rawMat(xraw)[,1]
xrawData.rt <- xraw_rt_dp[-dp_index]
```

Now :

```
xrawData.rt #contains the retention time.
```

Observation --> Using mzr package:

```
nc     <- mzR:::netCDFOpen(cdfFile)
ncData <- mzR:::netCDFRawData(nc)
mzR:::netCDFClose(nc)

ncData$rt #contains the same retention time for the same input !!!
```

Comment: and `identical(ncData$rt, hd$retentionTime)` is `TRUE`